# Is it possible to pass 2 requests to the vuex store?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

From the backend, 2 APIs come to me: one for cities, the other for the product category list. I call the axios method in the store where I change my state and show them in the component. But for some reason, only one method is executed (the city call method from the api), and the category list is not. As far as I know, the action is asynchronous. Provided code below:

Questionnaire.vue

```
<select 
                    type="choseCountry" 
                    class="questionnaire__questions-input questionnaire__input"
                    v-model="form.countryID"

                >
                    <option value="">Выберите страну</option>
                    <option v-for="country in COUNTRIES" :key="country.id" :value="country.id">{{country.name}}</option>
                </select>
                
                <select type="text" class="questionnaire__questions-input questionnaire__input">
                    <option value="">Выберите город</option>
                    <option v-for="city in cities" :key="city.id" :value="form.cityID">{{city.name}}</option>
                    
                </select>

<select class="questionnaire__input" type="text">
                                <option value="">Категория продуктов</option>
                                <option v-for="category in PRODUCT_CATEGORIES" :key="category.id" :value="form.category.id">{{category.name}}</option>
                            </select>
```

index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    countries: [],
    productCategories: []
  },
  getters: {
    COUNTRIES(state){
        return state.countries
    },
    PRODUCT_CATEGORIES(state){
        return state.productCategories
    }  
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_COUNTRIES_TO_STATE: (state, countries) => {
        state.countries = countries
    },
    SET_PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_TO_STATE: (state, productCategories) => {
        state.productCategories = productCategories
    },
  },
  actions: {
    GET_COUNTRIES_FROM_API({commit}) {
        return axios('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/borrower/countries/', {
            method: "GET"
        })
        .then((countries) => {
            commit('SET_COUNTRIES_TO_STATE', countries.data)
            return countries
        })
    },
    GET_PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_FROM_API({commit}) {
      return axios('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/borrower/category/', {
            method: "GET"
      })
      .then((productCategories) => {
            commit('SET_PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_TO_STATE', productCategories.data)
            return productCategories
      })
    }
  },
  modules: {
    //countries
    
  }
})
```

Only one get request is visible in the terminal:
[image]

Do I need to divide it all into modules to make it all work? What could be the problem?

Comment: The question doesn't contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , which is required. None of these actions are called in the code you posted.

Comment: Inside `Questionnaire.vue` call both API actions `this.$store.dispatch('GET_COUNTRIES_FROM_API');` and `this.$store.dispatch('GET_PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_FROM_API');` and

Comment: @cwoods i already call it with 
...mapActions([
            'GET_COUNTRIES_FROM_API',
            'GET_PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_FROM_API'
        ])